# Running PySpark on and IDE like Spyder?

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark

I could run PySpark from the terminal line and everything works fine.

```
~/spark-1.0.0-bin-hadoop1/bin$ ./pyspark
```

Welcome to

```
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 1.0.0
      /_/
```

Using Python version 2.7.6 (default, May 27 2014 14:50:58)

However when I try to this on a Python IDE

```
import pyspark
```

> ImportError: No module named pyspark

How do I import it like other Python libraries such numpy, scikit etc.?

Working in the terminal works fine, I just wanted to work in the IDE.

Comment: Is pyspark in your pythonpath? Is the pythonpath in the ide up to date?

Answer (score 5):

I wrote this launcher script a while back expressly for that purpose. I wanted to be able to interact with the pyspark shell from within the **bpython(1)** code-completion interpreter and **WING IDE**, or any IDE for that matter because they have code completion as well as provide a complete development experience. Learning Spark core by just typing 'pyspark' isn't good enough. So I wrote this. This was written in a **Cloudera CDH5** environment, but with a little tweaking you can get this to work in whatever your environment is (even manually installed ones).

**How to use:**

```
NOTE: You can place all of the following in your .profile (or equivalent).
(1) linux$ export MASTER='yarn-client | local[NN] | spark://host:port'
(2) linux$ export SPARK_HOME=/usr/lib/spark  # Your's will vary.
(3) linux$ export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/latest # Your's will vary.
(4) linux$ export NAMENODE='vps00' # Your's will vary.
(5) linux$ export PYSTART=${PYTHONSTARTUP}   # See in-line commends about the reason for the need for this alias to PYTHONSTARTUP.
(6) linux$ export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/etc/hadoop/conf # Your's will vary. This one may not be necessary to set. Try and see.
(7) linux$ export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/lib/hadoop      # Your's will vary. This one may not be necessary to set. Try and see.

(8) bpython -i /path/to/script/below  # The moment of truth. Note that this is 'bpython' (not just plain 'python', which would not give the code completion you desire).
>>> sc
<pyspark.context.SparkContext object at 0x2798110>
>>>
```

Now for use with an IDE, you simply determine how to specify the equivalent of a PYTHONSTARTUP script for that IDE, and set that to '/path/to/script/below'. For example, as I described in the in-line comments below, for WING IDE you simply set the key/value pair 'PYTHONSTARTUP=/path/to/script/below' inside the project's properties section.

See in-line comments for more information.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
# ===========================================================================
# Author: Noel Milton Vega (PRISMALYTICS, LLC.)
# ===========================================================================
# Start-up script for 'python(1)', 'bpython(1)', and Python IDE iterpreters
# when you want a 'client-mode' SPARK Shell (i.e. interactive SPARK shell)
# environment either LOCALLY, on a SPARK Standalone Cluster, or on SPARK
# YARN cluster. The code-sense/intelligence of bpython(1) and IDEs, in
# particular will aid in learning the SPARK core API.
# 
# This script basically (1) first sets up an environment to launch a SPARK
# Shell, then (2) launches the SPARK Shell using the 'shell.py' python script
# provided in the distribution's SPARK_HOME; and finally (3) imports our
# favorite Python modules (for convenience; e.g. numpy, scipy; etc.).
#
# IMPORTANT:
#  DON'T RUN THIS SCRIPT DIRECTLY. It is meant to be read in by interpreters
#  (similar, in that respect, to a PYTHONSTARTUP script).
#
#  Thus, there are two ways to use this file:
#  # We can't refer to PYTHONSTARTUP inside this file b/c that causes a recursion loop
#  # when calling this from within IDEs. So in step (0) we alias PYTHONSTARTUP to
#  # PYSTARTUP at the O/S level, and use that alias here (since no conflict with that).
#  (0): user$ export PYSTARTUP=${PYTHONSTARTUP} # We can't use PYTHONSTARTUP in this file
#  (1): user$ export MASTER='yarn-client | local[NN] | spark://host:port'
#       user$ bpython|python -i /path/to/this/file
#
#  (2): From within your favorite IDE, specify it as your python startup
#       script. For example, from within a WINGIDE project, set the following
#       variables within a WING Project: 'Project -> Project Properties':
#          'PYTHONSTARTUP=/path/to/this/very/file'
#          'MASTER=yarn-client | local[NN] | spark://host:port'
# ===========================================================================
import sys, os, glob, subprocess, random
namenode = os.getenv('NAMENODE')
SPARK_HOME = os.getenv('SPARK_HOME')
# ===========================================================================


# =================================================================================
# This functions emulates the action of "source" or '.' that exists in bash(1),
# and can be used to set PYTHON environment variables (in Pythons globals dict).
# =================================================================================
def source(script, update=True):
    proc = subprocess.Popen(". %s; env -0" % script, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    output = proc.communicate()[0]
    env = dict((line.split("=", 1) for line in output.split('\x00') if line))
    if update: os.environ.update(env)
    return env
# ================================================================================


# ================================================================================
# Here, we get the name of our current SPARK Assembly JAR file name (locally). We
# use that to create a HDFS URL that points to it's location in HDFS when using
# YARN (i.e. when 'export MASTER=yarn-client'; we ignore it otherwise).
# ================================================================================
# Remember to always upload/update your distribution's current SPARK Assembly JAR
# to HDFS like this:
#   $ hdfs dfs -mkdir -p /user/spark/share/lib" # Only necessary to do once!
#   $ hdfs dfs -rm "/user/spark/share/lib/spark-assembly-*.jar" # Remove old version.
#   $ hdfs dfs -put ${SPARK_HOME}/assembly/lib/spark-assembly-[0-9]*.jar /user/spark/share/lib/
# ================================================================================
SPARK_JAR_LOCATION = glob.glob(SPARK_HOME + '/lib/' + 'spark-assembly-[0-9]*.jar')[0].split("/")[-1]
SPARK_JAR_LOCATION = 'hdfs://' + namenode + ':8020/user/spark/share/lib/' + SPARK_JAR_LOCATION
# ================================================================================


# ================================================================================
# Update Pythons globals environment variable dict with necessary environment
# variables that the SPARK Shell will be looking for. Some we set explicitly via
# an in-line dictionary, as shown below. And the rest are set by 'source'ing the
# global SPARK environment file (although we could have included those explicitly
# here too, if we preferred not to touch that system-wide file -- and leave it as FCS).
# ================================================================================
spark_jar_opt = None
MASTER = os.getenv('MASTER') if os.getenv('MASTER') else 'local[8]'
if    MASTER.startswith('yarn-'): spark_jar_opt = ' -Dspark.yarn.jar=' + SPARK_JAR_LOCATION
elif  MASTER.startswith('spark://'): pass
else: HADOOP_HOME = ''
# ================================================================================


# ================================================================================
# Build '--driver-java-options' options for spark-shell, pyspark, or spark-submit.
# Many of these are set in '/etc/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf' (and thus
# commented out here, but left here for reference completeness).
# ================================================================================
# Default UI port is 4040. The next statement allows us to run multiple SPARK shells.
DRIVER_JAVA_OPTIONS = '-Dspark.ui.port=' + str(random.randint(1025, 65535))
DRIVER_JAVA_OPTIONS += spark_jar_opt if spark_jar_opt else ''
# ================================================================================

# ================================================================================
# Build PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS (i.e. the sames ones shown in 'pyspark --help'), and
# apply them to the O/S environment.
# ================================================================================
DRIVER_JAVA_OPTIONS = "'" + DRIVER_JAVA_OPTIONS + "'"
PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS = ' --master ' + MASTER # Remember to set MASTER on UNIX CLI or in the IDE!
PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS += ' --driver-java-options ' + DRIVER_JAVA_OPTIONS # Built above.
# ================================================================================
os.environ.update(source('/etc/spark/conf/spark-env.sh', update = False))
os.environ.update({ 'PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS' : PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS })
# ================================================================================


# ================================================================================
# Next, adjust 'sys.path' so SPARK Shell has the python modules it needs.
# ================================================================================
SPARK_PYTHON_DIR = SPARK_HOME + '/python'
PY4J = glob.glob(SPARK_PYTHON_DIR + '/lib/' + 'py4j-*-src.zip')[0].split("/")[-1]
sys.path = [SPARK_PYTHON_DIR, SPARK_PYTHON_DIR + '/lib/' + PY4J] + sys.path
# ================================================================================


# ================================================================================
# With our environment set, we start the SPARK Shell; and then to that, we add
# our favorite Python imports (e.g. numpy, scipy; etc).
# ================================================================================
print('PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS:' + PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS) # For visual debug.
execfile(SPARK_HOME + '/python/pyspark/shell.py', globals()) # Start the SPARK Shell.
execfile(os.getenv('PYSTARTUP')) # Next, load our favorite Python modules.
# ================================================================================
```

Enjoy and good luck! =:)

Answer (score 3):

Thanks [Ophir YokTon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/590335/ophir-yoktan)'s upper post, I Finally managed to do it with "Spark 1.4.1+ Spyder2.3.4.

Here I would like to give one summary on all my steps to do it, hope it can help some people in the similiar situations.

1. Add PYTHONPATH variable into .bashrc. (of course you can put into other relavent profile file)

> ```
> export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/:$PYTHONPATH
>
> export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip:$PYTHONPATH
> ```

2. Make it effective by

> ```
> source .bashrc
> ```

3. Create one copy of spyder as spyder.py on your spyder bin directory

> ```
> cp spyder spyder.py
> ```

4. Start Spyder IDE with following command

> ```
> spark-submit spyder.py
> ```

I implemented [the sample "simple app" from apache spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html) and passed the running test it in spyder environment. please refer to the picture "https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTv6s.gif"

Answer (score 0):

pyspark isn't probably at your pythonpath variable. Go to location where pyspark folder is located and add that folder to your class path.

Comment: Not working, it is in the path and still an import in not working

Answer (score 0):

1. If you just want to import the module , adding it to python path is enough
2. If you want to run complete scripts from the IDE, you can create a 'tool' that uses spark-submit to execute your script from the IDE (instead of normal run)
3. Specifically for spyder (or other IDE's that are written in python) you can run the IDE from within spark-submit

example:

```
spark-submit.cmd c:\Python27\Scripts\spyder.py
```

- note that I had to rename spyder to spyder.py - it appears spark submit relies on the extension do distinguish between python, java, or scala
- add any required parameters to spark-submit