# What to set `SPARK_HOME` to?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pythonpath, pyspark, apache-zeppelin

Installed apache-maven-3.3.3, scala 2.11.6, then ran:

```
$ git clone git://github.com/apache/spark.git -b branch-1.4
$ cd spark
$ build/mvn -DskipTests clean package
```

Finally:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/apache/incubator-zeppelin
$ cd incubator-zeppelin/
$ mvn install -DskipTests
```

Then ran the server:

```
$ bin/zeppelin-daemon.sh start
```

Running a simple notebook beginning with `%pyspark`, I got an error about `py4j` not being found. Just did `pip install py4j` ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26533169)).

Now I'm getting this error:

```
pyspark is not responding Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/zeppelin_pyspark.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
ImportError: No module named pyspark.conf
```

I've tried setting my `SPARK_HOME` to: `/spark/python:/spark/python/lib`. No change.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Two environment variables are required:

```
SPARK_HOME=/spark
PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python:$SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-VERSION-src.zip:$PYTHONPATH
```