# Trouble setting up/running Apache Spark with python (in windows 10)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm super new to spark, so my issues might have a "no duh" answer that I can't quite grasp.

Firstly, I downloaded spark 1.5.2 and extracted it. In the python folder, I tried to run pyspark, but it said something along the lines that it needs a **main**.py, so I copied **init**.py to **main**.py and started getting weird syntax errors. I realized I was using python 2.9, so I switched to 2.7 and got a different error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "C:\spark-1.5.2\python\pyspark\__main__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from pyspark.conf import SparkConf
ImportError: No module named pyspark.conf
```

I found this question that looked like the same error here: [What to set `SPARK_HOME` to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30824818/what-to-set-spark-home-to)

So I set up my environment variables as they did (except with C:/spark-1.5.2 instead of C:/spark), but that didn't fix the error for me. Then I realized they were using spark 1.4 from github. So I made a new folder and tried it as they did. I got stuck with the command:

```
build/mvn -DskipTests clean package
```

showing the error:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512M; support was removed in 8.0
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap
```

I tried adding "-XX:MaxHeapSize=3g" but no change. Noting the comment "support was removed in 8.0", I downloaded java 7, but that didn't change anything either.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just download pre-built version not a source. On a side note there is no such thing like Python 2.9...  Do you mean 2.6?

Comment: Thanks I'll try that, it was actually 2.7.9 my bad