# Can not launch sparkR

Tags: apache-spark, sparkr

I have installed Spark 2.0 and try the sparkR command. But command occurs error message like below. Others are OK (spark-shell, pyspark,,,). Please help...

[Error message]

Dongkils-MacBook:spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7 dongkillee$ sparkR
env: R: No such file or directory

Comment: can you share at least the whole error message ?

Answer (score 1):

> R: No such file or directory

In windows this error when system not found the R.exe file. Correct with change PATH environment

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like maybe SPARK_HOME is not set.  Run the Terminal app to get a command prompt and check with:
`ECHO $SPARK_HOME`

If the result does not list the directory where you installed Spark, then there's advice here:
 [What to set `SPARK_HOME` to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30824818/what-to-set-spark-home-to)

In R, or R Studio you can set SPARK_HOME from within R like this:

`spark_path <- '/path_to_spark/spark_dir'`
`Sys.setenv("SPARK_HOME" = spark_path)`

you also need to add the SparkR library location in R:

`spark_lib <- paste(spark_path, "/R/lib", sep="")`