# Django with Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Django application running against MySQL database. I want to introduce Big Data analytics in the application by connecting the same application to Spark which has data stored as hive tables. I can run queries and access the data through beeline. I want to run similar queries from Django app and show the result set in the app.

My environment is :

Spark 1.5.2
Thriftserver 2
Hive metastore on MySQL

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It's not really clear what exeactly your question is. To use the pyspark API you'd have to put pyspark and py4j on your `PYTHONPATH` and then read [this](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html#self-contained-applications). See also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26533169/why-cant-pyspark-find-py4j-java-gateway)

Comment: Thanks for your help.