# Unable to import SparkContext

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, mapr

I'm working on CentOS, I've setup `$SPARK_HOME` and also added path to `bin` in `$PATH`.

I can run `pyspark` from anywhere.

But when I try to create `python` file and uses this statement;

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
```

it throws following error

```
python pysparktask.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "pysparktask.py", line 1, in <module>
      from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyspark'
```

I tried to install it again using `pip`.

```
pip install pyspark
```

and it gives this error too.

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyspark (from versions: )
>   No matching distribution found for pyspark

**EDIT**

based on answer, I updated the code.

error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pysparktask.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
  File "/opt/mapr/spark/spark-2.0.1/python/pyspark/__init__.py", line 44, in <module>
    from pyspark.context import SparkContext
  File "/opt/mapr/spark/spark-2.0.1/python/pyspark/context.py", line 33, in <module>
    from pyspark.java_gateway import launch_gateway
  File "/opt/mapr/spark/spark-2.0.1/python/pyspark/java_gateway.py", line 31, in <module>
    from py4j.java_gateway import java_import, JavaGateway, GatewayClient
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'py4j'
```

Comment: I think for the error that you are getting after updating your code you can check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26533169/why-cant-pyspark-find-py4j-java-gateway

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following environment variable and also append spark's lib path to sys.path

```
import os
import sys

os.environ['SPARK_HOME'] = "/usr/lib/spark/"
sys.path.append("/usr/lib/spark/python/")

from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext # And then try to import SparkContext.
```

Comment: In your case you just need to add spark's lib path to sys.path

Comment: Thank you, based on your answer, I've updated the code, but getting some more errors.

Answer (score 2):

```
pip install -e /spark-directory/python/.
```

this installation will be solve your problem.
And you must edit bash_profile

```
export SPARK_HOME="/spark-directory"
```

Comment: above answer worked for me, as I'm using MapR, so I don't need to install it explicitly.