# Spyder-IDE and Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, spyder

I am currently using IPython Notebook with Apache Spark. I would like to switch to Spyder-ide. However, I do not know how make the Spyder python console to play nice with Spyder-ide. What are the required configuration to Sypder-ide with Spark? I am looking for code completion and the "run selection" feature to work correctly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Running PySpark on and IDE like Spyder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24249847/running-pyspark-on-and-ide-like-spyder)