# Register Spyder for Spark error

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spyder, pythonpath

I tried to set up a simple Standalone Spark cluster,
with a interface to Spyder. There have been several remarks in the spark mailing list and elsewhere, which give an guideline [how to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24249847/running-pyspark-on-and-ide-like-spyder/31649670#31649670).

This does not work for my setup though. Once I submit the script to `spark-submit`, I get the following error:

```
File "/home/philip/Programme/anaconda2/bin/spyder.py", line 4, in <module> import spyder.app.start
ImportError: No module named app.start
```

From my understanding, this has to do something with the `$PYTHONPATH` variable. I already changed the path to the py4j module (in current spark version 2.1.0, it is `py4j-0.10.4` instead of the listed one.

My `.bashrc` file looks currently like this:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
export JRE_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
export SPARK_HOME=~/Programme/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7
export PATH=$PATH:$SPARK_HOME/bin
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python:$SPARK_HOME/python/build:$PYTHONPATH
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/:$PYTHONPATH
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip:$PYTHONPATH
export PATH=$PATHusr/bin/spyder

export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}home/philip/Programme/anaconda2/bin/

# added by Anaconda2 4.3.0 installer
export PATH=/home/philip/Programme/anaconda2/bin:$PATH
```

If somebody has encountered a similar issue, help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered a similar error. The reason in my case was that I had not set `PYTHONPATH`. You should try setting this to your installation of python.
So instead of:

`export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}home/philip/Programme/anaconda2/bin/`

Try

`export PYTHONPATH=/home/philip/Programme/anaconda2/bin/python2.7`

I was able to get my spyder setup going by using the following code in the spyder editor window:

```
import os
import sys

if 'SPARK_HOME' not in os.environ:
    os.environ['SPARK_HOME']='/home/ramius/spark-2.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7'
SPARK_HOME=os.environ['SPARK_HOME']

if 'PYTHONPATH' not in os.environ:
    os.environ['PYTHONPATH']='/home/ramius/anaconda2/bin/python2.7'
PYTHONPATH=os.environ['PYTHONPATH']

sys.path.insert(0,os.path.join(SPARK_HOME,"python"))
sys.path.insert(0,os.path.join(SPARK_HOME,"python","lib"))
sys.path.insert(0,os.path.join(SPARK_HOME,"python","lib","pyspark.zip"))
sys.path.insert(0,os.path.join(SPARK_HOME,"python","lib","py4j-0.10.4-src.zip"))

from pyspark import SparkContext
```

Hope that helps.